# EventBridge and Lambda different inputs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I need to run a Lambda Function with a Thousand of different inputs, I did it with a Event Bus and another lambda that send the events reading de input from a DynamoDB.

Is that the best way to do this? The lambda that send the events to the event bus, take too much time, and I need to do a loop to send 10 entries at time for the event bus limitations, in boto3.

Comment: Why do you need EB? You can "joint" the two lambdas using SQS or SNS, or Even step functions.

Comment: I think a step function would work well.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't say it. I'm using EB, because I need to run the function (with the thousands of different inputs) every 8 hours.

Answer (score 1):

You can still trigger a stepfunction from Eventbridge and perform a parallel scan with dynamodb to produce the input for the lambda.

Alternatively you can update every dynamodb item with lambda or stepfunction and use dynamodb streams to trigger your lambda.

Comment: Is this approach better that use a lambda function to read from DynamoDB and Send 
 a SNS for every input?

Comment: It depends on the throughput you are expecting. If it is a long running process (lambda has a maximum timeout) you are better off with stepfunction